# Apache RewriteRule in .htaccess short URL not changing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Have been trying to shorten the url of my site with `.htaccess` but still is not working for example of what am trying to do, I have a link `www.mysite.com/index.php?p=update&code=1234`
which I want to shorten to `www.mysite.com/update/1234` and this is my htaccess codes am using

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteRule ^update/([0-9]+)$ www.mysite.com/?p=update&code=$1
```

But it keeps showing me `www.mysite.com/index.php?p=update&code=1234` each time i goto 
`www.mysite.com/update/1234`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It gets rid of your destination `www.mysite.com` since you are not redirecting with an `R` flag; this is all behind the scenes on your server. And it explicitly sets `index.php` in `index.php?p=update&code=$1`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteRule ^update/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=update&code=$1 [L]
```

Then if I set the following simple code in `index.php`:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';
```

The URL stays the same, but the output in the browser will be:

```
Array
(
    [p] => update
    [code] => 1234
)
```

Comment: i dont get you, should i just add [L] or what do you mean?